# Filling out a PDF form with values from textbox.text and printing the PDF after the PDF is filled

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, pdf, itext

I have search the web and have not found a solution to do this.

I have a VB.net form with a Dataset of costumers, and i want to take the contact information in the textbox.text and fill out a PDF form, and print it.

Itextsharp is mention every where to create a pdf, not to fill out one and print it, and i found a promising code, im not really familiar with vb.net at all, this is my first program.

This is the code i found that i think would work...

```
Imports System
Imports System.IO
Imports System.Xml
Imports iTextSharp
Imports iTextSharp.text
Imports iTextSharp.text.pdf
Imports iTextSharp.text.xml
Imports System.Security

Private Sub xmltopdf()
    Dim pdfTemp As String = "C:\ExampleTemplate.pdf" ' ---> It's the original pdf form you want to fill
    Dim newFile As String = "C:\NewFile.Pdf" ' ---> It will generate new pdf that you have filled from your program

    ' ------ READING -------

    Dim pdfReader As New PdfReader(pdfTemp)

    ' ------ WRITING -------

    ' If you don’t specify version and append flag (last 2 params) in below line then you may receive “Extended Features” error when you open generated PDF
    Dim pdfStamper As New PdfStamper(pdfReader, New FileStream(newFile, FileMode.Create), "\6c", True)

    Dim pdfFormFields As AcroFields = pdfStamper.AcroFields

    ' ------ SET YOUR FORM FIELDS ------

    pdfFormFields.SetField("Company", "Parth Dave & Co.")
    pdfFormFields.SetField("SalesOrder", "1234456")
    pdfFormFields.SetField("InstallAddress", "Lorimer Street")
    pdfFormFields.SetField("Suburb", "Port Melbourne")
    pdfFormFields.SetField("Post_Code", "3207")
    pdfFormFields.SetField("ClientContact", "Parth")
    pdfFormFields.SetField("ClientPhone", "0402020202")

    pdfStamper.FormFlattening = False

    ' close the pdf
    pdfStamper.Close()
    ' pdfReader.close() ---> DON"T EVER CLOSE READER IF YOU'RE GENERATING LOTS OF PDF FILES IN LOOP
End Sub
```

I get errors on the Imports and dont know what the import are..

I have added the itextsharp.dll so that should be ok..

If anyone could help me out or send me in the right direction it would be much appreciated.

Comment: did you add a reference to the itextsharp.dll? `Project|Add Reference|Browse` find your dll and select it

Comment: Actually, I just drug your code into a project and used the NuGet package manager to install iTextSharp and other than on Option Strict error on your "\6c", everything went as expected. Not a single error shows.

Comment: tried to remove it and add it again... still not working

Comment: Wait, you do have you imports outside of the class right? They should be before any other code.

Comment: No, i did not :), i hope i can get it to do want i want now :) thank you

Comment: I went to Manage Tools menu > Nuget Package Manager > Nuget Nuget Packages for Solution  The I searched for pdf. Installed iTextSharp. After that Intellisense told me what to import. Still got a red squiggle under `"\6c"` The c goes outside the quotes but there can only be a single character. If it is version 6 then `"6"c` should do it.

Comment: I have no problems with the 6c, everything is working now :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put the Imports outside of the class.